# ActiveModelSerializer converts Hash to JsonArray after upgrading ruby 2.1.4 and rails 4.2.0beta4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have the following line of code in my controller:

```
render json: {token: user.token}, status: 200
```

It used to respond as below: (root node is disabled by default)

```
{'token': 'ace814a7dd50acda5a76ff7e4c9f7252'}
```

Now I get the result as an array and that doesn't work for me.

```
[["token", "ace814a7dd50acda5a76ff7e4c9f7252"]]
```

How can I configure my Rails application to get my previous behavior back?

Comment: what version of AMS?

Comment: gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: '0-9-stable'

This is the from my Gemfile

Comment: revert back to `0.8`, `0.9` is a mess.

Comment: Changing to ```gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: 'master'``` fixed my issue. I couldn't think to change the AMS version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want me to recap this in an answer?

Comment: Damn it! 0-8-stable and master causes much more problems. 0-9-stable just better except hash to array problem. I am not sure to recap that in answer. AMS is totally mess.